# How to pass diffrent id's for django summernote form

Tags: django, summernote

I have a comment form for a model in django and I render multiple instance of the form on my template using SummernoteWidget. The problem is the form only submits the first instance of the form and ignores the rest because they share the same Id.

How do I pass multiple Id's for each form instance

My comment form

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget())

    class Meta:
       model = Comment
       fields = ['body']
```

My template

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Comment</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: I can only see a single field in this form!? Are you ending up with many fields using the exact same code?

Comment: yeah @dstrants .

Comment: post your view method as well. You are getting form from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see mistakes in your model form. The model form should not have any field. You should describe them in META tag.

```
class Author(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)
birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name', 'title', 'birth_date'].
```

as shown above. Also, for summernote widget should also be assigned in the **META** section.

```
class FormFromSomeModel(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = SomeModel
    widgets = {
        'foo': SummernoteWidget(),
        'bar': SummernoteInplaceWidget(),
    }
```

Please, when calling form in the template use safe as well:

```
{{ foobar|safe }}
```

After all these issues are fixed, you can assign different names to multiple forms(if you have any) in the view.py file within the related method.